# loop through elements on button click, then hide all, then start loop again with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop through a collection of elements, by showing each one on a button click (which I've managed to do successfully).

The next part I'm trying to do is, after the last element of the collection is shown, the next button click should hide all elements, and then the next button click should start the loop from the beginning.

UPDATE: I think I'm almost there... it's now clearing the images once it gets to the end, but the next click jumps already to the second image and skips the first one. How do I get it to clear all images but then still start again at the beginning, "i=0"? (codepen and code below has been updated)

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/rrosegregoryy/pen/qBXVKVW

And my code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
  //Elements to loop through
  var images = $(".click-image");
  //Start at 0
  i = 0;

  function showImage() {
    //Loop through elements
    $(images).each(function (index) {
      if (i == index) {
        //Show active element
        $(this).show();
      } else if (i == $(images).length) {
        //Show message
        $(this).show();
        //Reset if list number is reached
        $(images).hide();
        i = 0;
      }
    });

    i++;
  }

  //Run function on button click
  $(".and-button").click(showImage);
});
```

```css
.and-button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 42px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.click-image {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.is--1 {
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 10%;
}

.is--2 {
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
}

.is--3 {
  top: 15%;
  right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click-image is--1"></div>
<div class="click-image is--2"></div>
<div class="click-image is--3"></div>
<div class="and-button">&</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mplungjan and playing around with their code, I got it working. I don't really understand why but below is the final jquery code and here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/rrosegregoryy/pen/vYJoRzP

```
$(function() {
  //Elements to loop through
  const images = $(".click-image");
  //Start at 0
  let i = 0;
  const showImage = () => {
    if (i === $(images).length) {
      console.log("done"); // or reveal some other element
      $(images).hide();
      i = 0;
      return; // comment this out to show the first image right away
    }
    //$(images).hide(); // remove  if you want to keep the shown images on screen 
    $(images).eq(i).show()
    i++;
  };
  //Run function on button click
  $(".and-button").on("click", showImage);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely mean this?

I assume you only want to show one  at a time. If not, remove the .hide statement

```js
$(function() {
  //Elements to loop through
  const images = $(".click-image");
  //Start at 0
  let i = 0;
  const showImage = () => {
    if (i > $(images).length) {
      console.log("done"); // or reveal some other element
      i = 0;
      $(images).hide(); 
      // return; // comment this out to show the first image right away
    }
    $(images).eq(i).show()
    i++;
  };
  //Run function on button click
  $(".and-button").on("click", showImage);
});
```

```css
.and-button {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 42px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.click-image {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.is--1 {
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 10%;
}

.is--2 {
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
}

.is--3 {
  top: 15%;
  right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click-image is--1">img1</div>
<div class="click-image is--2">img2</div>
<div class="click-image is--3">img3</div>
<div class="and-button">&</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help!! I actually want each image to stay so the number of images on the screen increases with each click and then ALL disappear at once and it loops from the beginning. I tried to comment out .hide statement as you suggested and this keeps the images there, but it doesn't clear them and loop from beginning, see my updated codepen: https://codepen.io/rrosegregoryy/pen/vYJoRzP

Do you have a suggestion for what I could try? Thanking you in advance!!

Comment: Oh I think I'm almost there... it's now clearing the images once it gets to the end, but the next click jumps already to the second image and skips the first one... see another codepen: https://codepen.io/rrosegregoryy/pen/qBXVKVW

Comment: Sorry I’m not near a computer for a few days

Comment: No problem - thanks so much for your help so far! Do you think you know how to fix the last issue (skipping the first image after clearing them all)?

Comment: I’ll look in a minute

Comment: My code now clears them all and you have to click again to see the first

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Hey I'm really sorry but your answer isn't quite what I was after... I want each image to stay so the number of images on the screen increases with each click and then ALL disappear at once and it loops from the beginning. I've almost got it working in this codepen: https://codepen.io/rrosegregoryy/pen/qBXVKVW 
the images are all appearing and then clearing once it gets to the end, but the next click jumps already to the second image and skips the first one.

Comment: Okay, I got it working! I used your code but moved the hide statement from after the if statement into the if statement itself. You can see it working here: https://codepen.io/rrosegregoryy/pen/vYJoRzP